# How to get specific value text from XML by PHP xpath

Tags: php, xpath

I have an xml like that :

```
$strxml= "<products>
<product>
    <name>Product Parent</name>
    <sku>3151907</sku>
    <parent_sku></parent_sku>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>Product Variation</name>
    <sku></sku>
    <parent_sku>3151907</parent_sku>
  </product>
</products>";
```

I want to select all child products that no longer have parents (previously deleted).
For example, get all products with sku = 3151907
I tried this but doesn't work

```
$has_parent = $xml->xpath("//product/sku[text()='3151907']");
```

Comment: your xpath is only selecting the SKU, you need to select a parent then add a pattern, `//product[sku='3151907']` should work with out the need for `text()`

Comment: also if you want ones with an empty parent sku `//product[parent_sku[not(text())]]`

Comment: Your XPath appears to work OK but the question title and the XPath expression seem at odds with the statement `"I want to select all child products that no longer have parents (previously deleted)"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all `product[parent_sku`] (with a value) that don't have a matching `product[sku]` value, you need something like this:

```
$has_parent = $xml->xpath("//product/parent_sku[text()][not(text()=//product/sku/text())]");
```

If (as in your example) `products` is the root element of your xml that consists of `product` child's, you can increase performance by using this Xpath:

```
/products/product/parent_sku[text()][not(text()=/products/product/sku/text())]
```